# Is this crack normal house settling?

Tags: drywall, walls, structural, crack

Our place was built in 1973 but we just moved in a year ago. We noticed a small crack around our lofted window (see pic) but thought it was ok. Just recently the crack has now extended down to our floor (see link). Additionally, from the outside along the same wall as the crack it looks like the siding is warping (see link). We recently got a lot of rain but not sure that's what's causing this level of cracking. Is this something to be concerned about?

This is on the second floor of our house. We have a raised foundation supported by beams.

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNINk-653tOofiasR3yET4aHO-jslD8auouamGfkjrYpqabq5qLIkX8tZu6rNGhyQ?pli=1&key=dlZOZkpJVm1hSGZiRWhObEszLWphVURUOWJtQ2hn

[image]

[image: outside]

Comment: That's not a question we can answer through the internet tubes. Have a local expert take a look. Some homes have regular seasonal movement.

Comment: It's pretty pricey to have a structural engineer come out and look so was hoping to get a sense of if this is serious enough to warrant the cost.

Comment: I don't usually default to credentialled structural engineers. Anyone with legitimate construction experience should be able to give you some insight, often for a beer. Ask around. :)

Comment: A recommended building contractor or your local building inspector can give advice also.  A structural enginneer might not be needed unless major work is required.

Comment: An SE might be necessary to design a remediation plan _should one be required_. However, as others have suggested, there are others who may be able to give an educated opinion on what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both sides are covering the actual structural wall, it is hard to say/see.

There is a deformation on both sides which would indicate structural problems.

At first look I was going to say it is just the drywall crack, but not so sure now.

Since it rained a lot, the ground got softened leading to a shift in the foundation.

The only way to know for sure would be to get a professional to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

water erosion is a thing and you should consider fixing it as soon as possible (at least from the outside) before the winter because erosion due to ice expansion is even more serious. also in the outside crack, a variety of animals (insects) could move in (during the summertime) and erode it to a greater extent. structurally it looks like a no-deal (the house won't collapse due to this at this stage). it is advised to investigate it more (with some leader) and check if those cracks are just on the surface (eg. created from outside-in) or connected (created from inside-out)

Comment: In addition to water erosion, the drawing down of aquifers causes the ground to subside as well.  If that's happening and then you get heavy rains (e.g.: in California), that could cause some movement.